# Golang take nested value from mongo.SingleResult

Tags: mongodb, go

In Golang I read a value from a database.

```
    findOptions := options.FindOneOptions{}
findOptions.SetSort(bson.D{{"foo", -1}})
var valueFromDatabase *mongo.SingleResult
valueFromDatabase = clients.MongoClient.Database("foo").Collection("foo").FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{})
```

Is it possible to get a specific position, much like you would in an array?

Not working sample code, how it should fetch the values:

```
valueFromDatabase.NestedObject.Array[0].Value
```

Background is. A generic approach should be used so that the solution works independently of the structure of the BSON document. Which fields are to be read out is known from a slice.

The following approach was tried: The conversion to a json destroys the Mongo encryption.

Comment: Decode into a map (`bson.M`).

Comment: For the first stage I can do it without any problems. How do you do that with nested structures? Could you please post a brief example please?

Comment: Use a type assertion if a value is another document or array.

Comment: working. Thank you. Does someone need an example?

Comment: @MarkusBach that would be nice!